# Show in-app purchase price programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I have the following code added to my In App Purchase ViewController, but I want to show the price along with the text I have already added

My code for calling the price is:

```
 _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
```

I want to call the price from that string after 'Upgrade for' text on my button

```
[buyButton setTitle:@"Upgrade for" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Do you want to setTitle like 'Upgrade for <price> <currency sign>'?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here (haven't tested), but is there a reason something like this won't work?

```
NSString *buttonTitleString= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upgrade for %@", priceString];
[buyButton setTitle:buttonTitleString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or, to do it in one line

```
[buyButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upgrade for %@", priceString] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

where priceString is your string for the price, likely using the formatter you described in the question.

Comment: My _priceFormatter string is returning (null) any idea?

Comment: Looks like Valentin (below) got to it before I could get the formatter checked out. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];

NSString* titleWithPriceAndCurrencySign = [formatter stringFromNumber:product.price];

[buyButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Upgrade for %@", titleWithPriceAndCurrencySign] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Sometimes you may want to customize standard price representation for some locale. For example, in russian locale prices are presented with redundant zeros - `33,00 RUB`. I'd like to have a short notation - `33 r.`. So I add following code:

```
if ([product.priceLocale.localeIdentifier hasSuffix:@"currency=RUB"])
{
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    [formatter setCurrencySymbol:@"r."];
}
```